# Using AdControl in windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, scroll

How to make Adcontrol always visible at bottom of the screen. Right now it is going at the end of the screen.

I have pivot control, in it I have Listbox which is dynamically binding with data. After pivot control I have adcontrol. So when the data grows in Listbox, adcontrol goes down. How to make it fixed at the bottom.

Comment: so there is no way around to make it always at bottom, like the way we do in web. Also the listbox I am using I am not able to scroll down to bottom, even if I am adding the listbox inside the scrollviewer

Comment: The listbox itself contains ScrollViewer. If you don't like Popup, you can set the listbox height to fixed size. And consider using Grid with 2 row (one for listbox, and one for Ad)

Comment: I don't want to specify the fixed size, that's the problem. Is there any other way ?

Answer (score 0):

Your root layout control should be a grid which wraps the pivot and ad control:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <toolkit:Pivot Grid.Row="0">
        <ListBox>
           ...
        </ListBox>
    </toolkit:Pivot>

    <AdControl Grid.Row="1"/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can most certainly use the popup call and contain the ad in it. My solution below is using a canvas to hold the ad in which would net the same result, but may be more familiar with what you've used before.

Also, you don't have to set the height and width of your listbox/pivot container if you didn't want to. What the canvas/popup would do is be outside of the pivot control, so it is always on top of the stack.

For instance (approximating your code)

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
   <controls:Pivot>
       <!--PivotItemOne-->
       <controls:PivotItem>
           <Grid>
            <!-- code -->
           </Grid>
       </controls:PivotItem>

   ....

   </controls:Pivot>

 <Canvas x:Name="Ad" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="Auto" Height="80"/>
   <!-- or whatever height you want depending on ad size -->

</Grid>
```

This way, the canvas is always at the bottom of the page and hovering over your pivot control. It will not matter if the pivot changes as it is outside of the Pivot control.

If you ever needed to get rid of the Ad visibility or destroying the container itself, it would require less work overall than changing your listbox/pivot size.